# Error in Content Query Web part

Tags: content-query-web-part

I am facing the issue when adding a content query and configure its properties to select a list I get the attached error.
[image: Error!CbqPickerSelectListTitle]

Comment: Please post the query you are using

Comment: In the content query tool part --> In Query category --> i am selecting the third option "Show item from following list". When i click on browse button i am facing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced this before, couldn't find a quick solution but the easiest way to get around this problem is simply to type in the location of the list!

So, if you access your site like this: `https://server/Site/` then your lists are probably stored in `https://server/Site/Lists/NameOfList`

In this case, just type in the textbox: `/Site/Lists/NameOfList` and hit enter. It will work without needing to use the picker (which, in all honesty, just takes time)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and got it resolved. The issue is because one of the library on the site is corrupted and was showing an error when I open it. I deleted the library and it resolved the issue. So I suggest to check all the lists and libraries on the site. If you need the library, you need to fix the issue with the library.